# how to override setObject: forKey: method (in Foundation Framework)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

When Set nil value in dictionary then it is crashed.
Below is the code.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [@{} mutableCopy];
[dic setObject:nil forKey:@"test"];
```

this code will be crash. so is there a way to override setObject:forKey: to make it do not crash when nil is pass to it,just like this:`[dic setObject:nil forKey:@"test"];`

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: try setValue:forKey: instead of setObject: forKey: or use  [NSNull null] instead of nil.

Comment: @HardikShekhat: can i override this method?

Comment: sorry, maybe my state unclear,my means that how can i rewrite it? i try to override it by category,but still this method of system framework is work not mine.is there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use only `NSString` instances as keys, you can safely use next category from `NSKeyValueCoding.h`:

```
    @interface NSMutableDictionary<KeyType, ObjectType>(NSKeyValueCoding)

    /* Send -setObject:forKey: to the receiver, unless the value is nil, in which case send -removeObjectForKey:.
    */
    - (void)setValue:(nullable ObjectType)value forKey:(NSString *)key;

    @end
```

If you want to use other types as keys, or avoid exception in case when key is nil, you can create your own category to NSMutableDictionary. For example:

```
    @interface NSMutableDictionary (CocoaFix)

    - (void)setObjectOrNil:(id)object forKeyOrNil:(id)key;

    @end

    @implementation NSMutableDictionary (CocoaFix)

    - (void)setObjectOrNil:(id)object forKeyOrNil:(id)key {
        if (object && key) {
            [self setObject:object forKey:key];
        }
    }

    @end
```

Note that there is no way to override original `setObject:forKey:` method for `NSMutableDictionary`. Normally, method swizzling in categories can be used to do that. But `NSMutableDictionary` is actually the class cluster. Private subclasses of `NSMutableDictionary` do the real work under the hood. Each of subclasses has own `setObject:forKey:` implementation, because this method is primitive one. You can read more about class clusters at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't, from the documentation of NSDictionary:

> In general, a key can be any object (provided that it conforms to the
>   NSCopying protocol—see below), but note that when using key-value
>   coding the key must be a string (see Key-Value Coding Fundamentals).
>   **Neither a key nor a value can be nil**; if you need to represent a null
>   value in a dictionary, you should use NSNull.

Answer (score 0):

Anyhow you want to escape crash. right? For this purpose, you code should inside try-catch block

```
@try {
    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [@{} mutableCopy];
    [dic setObject:nil forKey:@"test"];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"%@",exception.reason);
}
@finally {

}
```

//you can do by this way

```
NSNull *nullValue=[[NSNull alloc]init];//globally decalare
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [@{} mutableCopy];
[dic setObject:dic?dic:nullValue forKey:@"test"];
```

Comment: because nil pass to it the app will be crashed, i want to digest this issue by myself(eg:i can return this method immediately if a nil pass to it) and do not  cause the app crash, maybe i can avoid this issue by verifying the arg (if arg is nil) before invoke `setObject:forKey:`, but there are too many place need to add the verify code, so i want to know if i can override this method?